# Getting 2020-02-29T00:00:00.000Z for March using momentjs or Date()

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to get start and end of the current month but for march it is giving me the start date as 
2020-02-29T00:00:00.000Z

Using momentjs

```
    var firstDay = new moment().startOf('month').utcOffset(0);
    firstDay.set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0});
    var lastDay = new moment().endOf('month').utcOffset(0);
    lastDay.set({hour:23,minute:59,second:59,millisecond:0})
```

Using Date()

```
    var date = new Date(),
        y = date.getFullYear(),
        m = date.getMonth();
    var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
    var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 1);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try startOf / endOf followed by `utcOffset()`

> **Note:** startOf - set to the first of this month, 12:00 am

```js
var firstDay = new moment('2020-02-29T00:00:00.000Z').utcOffset(0).startOf('month');
console.log(firstDay.format())

var lastDay = new moment('2020-02-29T00:00:00.000Z').utcOffset(0).endOf('month');
console.log(lastDay.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For the last day, i have to set the hours,minute,second and millisecond to 23:59:59:0

Answer (score 0):

For march it should be like this using `utcOffset(0)` then call the function `startof()`:

```js
var startDay = new moment().utcOffset(0).startOf('month').format();
var endDay = new moment().utcOffset(0).endOf('month').format();

console.log(startDay);
console.log(endDay);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var firstDay = new moment('2020-02-29T00:00:00.000Z').utcOffset(0).startOf('month');
console.log(firstDay.format())

var lastDay = new moment('2020-02-29T00:00:00.000Z').utcOffset(0).endOf('month');
console.log(lastDay.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.